# Segue To View Controller Inside Of A UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

How do you segue from a ViewController to a ViewController located in a UITableView (which is in a NavigationController)?

[Image of Storyboard with description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1KsI.png)

I can Control-Drag from my "DetailButton" to the "DetailViewController", but it is not displayed in the navigation controller if you do that. The NavigationBar should still allow a user to go back to the UITableView, even if they segued here from the "DetailButton".

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with. If anyone else has a better way, please post it here.

Storyboard Steps:

1. Control-Drag from the "DetailButton" to the Navigation Controller to create a segue. Give this segue the identifier "detailSegue".
2. Control-Drag from the UITableViewCell you would like to link to DetailViewController to the DetailViewController. Give this segue the name "showDetail".

UITableViewController Steps:

```
var shouldSegueToDetail = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    // Check if we should segue to DetailViewController
    if shouldSegueToDetail {
        // Reset flag
        shouldSegueToDetail = false

        // Go to DetailViewController
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
    }
}
```

OriginalViewController Steps:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {
        let navigationVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let tableVC = navigationVC.viewControllers[0] as! UITableViewController
        tableVC.shouldSegueToDetail = true
    }
}
```

Option:

Instead of making a segue from the UITableViewCell to the DetailViewController, you could probably call UITableView's selectRow method with the IndexPath of the item you want selected.